# create SharePoint 2013 portal with custom master page?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

what is best practices to create SharePoint 2013 portal with custom master page from scratch ?
1- create web application from central administration
2-create site collection 
3-enable variation to have Arabic and English
4-Upload html , css ,and js files 
5- using design manager to convert html file 
6- create solution in visual studio to create user control and custom web parts 
any advises ???

Comment: I Get This Error After Create Master Page System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure feature enable at the Site Collection level and SharePoint Server Publishing feature at web level.

The error you provided is due to that. Once you enable both of these features in Share Point 2013, you can see an option of 
Master pages and page layouts under **Web Designer Galleries** section.

Once you get your master page there you can set your master page as Site Master Page and System Master Page  from Master Page section in **Look and Feel** section.

Let me know if this help you or not